# PHP Duration Dropdown

Tags: php, loops, datetime

I am creating a dropdown on a page where a person can select the duration of a meeting. While designing, I just hard coded a handful of options but now I need to create something more elegant..

This is what the outcome needs to be:

```
  <option value="15">15 minutes</option>
  <option value="30">30 minutes</option>
  <option value="45">45 minutes</option>
  <option value="60">1 hour</option>
  <option value="75">1 hour 15 minutes</option>
  <option value="90">1 hour 30 minutes</option>
  <option value="105">1 hour 45 minutes</option>
  <option value="120">2 hours</option>
```

I need this to continue for a total of 24 hours in 15 min increments.

I started with something like this which produces something in the right direction but as far as formatting it with text etc is where I am lost.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++){
 for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j+=15){
  echo $i . ':'.$j.'<br />';
 }
}
```

Any easy way to handle this with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

echo "<select>";

for($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++){
    for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j += 15){
        if ($i === 0 && $j === 0){
            //do nothing
        }
        else{
            //get string for hours
            switch($i){
                case 0:
                    $hours = "";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $hours = "1 hour";
                    break;
                default:
                    $hours = $i . " hours";
                    break;
            }

            //get string for minutes
            switch($j){
                case 0:
                    $minutes = "";
                    break;
                default:
                    $minutes = $j . " minutes";
                    break;
            }

            $value = ($hours * 60) + $minutes;

            //output
            echo "<option value='" . $value . "'>" . $hours . " " . $minutes . "</option>";
        }
    }
}

echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like this:

```
<?php
$startTime = strtotime("00:00");
$endTime = strtotime("24:00");
for ($i = $startTime; $i <= $endTime; $i = $i + 15*60)
{
echo date("H:i", $i);
}
```

or create new DateTime object and use [DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) for incrementing till the needed end time.

Comment: Note that the output from this would be different than the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did it:

```
for ($min_total=15; $min_total<=1440; $min_total += 15) {
    $hours = floor($min_total / 60);
    $min = $min_total % 60;

    $text = '';
    if ($hours > 0) {
        $text .= $hours;
        $text .= ' hour';
        if ($hours != 1) {
            $text .= 's';
        }
        $text .= ' ';
    }
    if ($min > 0) {
        $text .= $min . ' minutes';
    }
    echo "<option value='" . $min_total . "'>" . trim($text) . "</option>\n";
}
```

And the result:

```
<option value='15'>15 minutes</option>
<option value='30'>30 minutes</option>
<option value='45'>45 minutes</option>
<option value='60'>1 hour</option>
<option value='75'>1 hour 15 minutes</option>
<option value='90'>1 hour 30 minutes</option>
<option value='105'>1 hour 45 minutes</option>
<option value='120'>2 hours</option>
<option value='135'>2 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='150'>2 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='165'>2 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='180'>3 hours</option>
<option value='195'>3 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='210'>3 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='225'>3 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='240'>4 hours</option>
<option value='255'>4 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='270'>4 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='285'>4 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='300'>5 hours</option>
<option value='315'>5 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='330'>5 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='345'>5 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='360'>6 hours</option>
<option value='375'>6 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='390'>6 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='405'>6 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='420'>7 hours</option>
<option value='435'>7 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='450'>7 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='465'>7 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='480'>8 hours</option>
<option value='495'>8 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='510'>8 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='525'>8 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='540'>9 hours</option>
<option value='555'>9 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='570'>9 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='585'>9 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='600'>10 hours</option>
<option value='615'>10 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='630'>10 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='645'>10 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='660'>11 hours</option>
<option value='675'>11 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='690'>11 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='705'>11 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='720'>12 hours</option>
<option value='735'>12 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='750'>12 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='765'>12 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='780'>13 hours</option>
<option value='795'>13 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='810'>13 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='825'>13 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='840'>14 hours</option>
<option value='855'>14 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='870'>14 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='885'>14 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='900'>15 hours</option>
<option value='915'>15 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='930'>15 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='945'>15 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='960'>16 hours</option>
<option value='975'>16 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='990'>16 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='1005'>16 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='1020'>17 hours</option>
<option value='1035'>17 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='1050'>17 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='1065'>17 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='1080'>18 hours</option>
<option value='1095'>18 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='1110'>18 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='1125'>18 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='1140'>19 hours</option>
<option value='1155'>19 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='1170'>19 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='1185'>19 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='1200'>20 hours</option>
<option value='1215'>20 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='1230'>20 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='1245'>20 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='1260'>21 hours</option>
<option value='1275'>21 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='1290'>21 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='1305'>21 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='1320'>22 hours</option>
<option value='1335'>22 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='1350'>22 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='1365'>22 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='1380'>23 hours</option>
<option value='1395'>23 hours 15 minutes</option>
<option value='1410'>23 hours 30 minutes</option>
<option value='1425'>23 hours 45 minutes</option>
<option value='1440'>24 hours</option>
```